# How to fix attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python

[image]

based on this file structure in the picture, why I always got `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`? It is quite confuesd, and anyone can tell me some methods and the reasons?

Comment: See https://peps.python.org/pep-0366, but consider whether `find_similar_page_of_query.py` should be a module at all, rather than a script that uses absolute imports.

Comment: Use `python -m health_science_chatbot.generate_classification.data.find_similar_page_of_query` if you want to run your script _as a module_ where it knows where it lives in the hierarchy. When you just run `python path/to/somescript.py`, its module name is just `__main__`; it doesn't have any concept of living somewhere in a hierarchy so relative imports aren't available.